# Co-workers used a bot to have my pitch win the people’s choice award for a conference. I have conflicting feelings and don’t know what to think

Tags: software, fraud

Last week, there was an industry conference where I was selected to pitch for my company.

Things have been difficult for me professionally recently as I didn’t get a major contract and keep worrying that I can’t keep up. I was really putting in the time for the pitch, hoping that it would give me some clarity. I’ve never been a confident person and never really got away from the feedback cycle in university, where there were always little bits of good news.

I do my pitch. It goes fine, but there was no obvious love from the audience. The applause sounds socially obligated. I thought that I had failed and wasn’t in a good mood.

The voting URL was put on the projector with a code and everyone was to vote while we got dinner. We were going to go as a team, but two devs said they had to deal with a “server problem” and took out their laptops and went to the corner. Not too unusual so far, as things happen.

We eat and go back to our seats. 15 minutes after the voting closed, they announced that the process “had clearly not been fair” so they decided to redo the vote in a 10 minute window. The two devs had another “server fault” and went off again, returning 15 minutes later, just in time to be there when I won.

I was so happy for the first time in a long time. No longer trapped under the rubble of past failure. There was joy in my heart and confidence in my voice.

Because I didn’t feel obligated to keep working late, I went to see my mom over the weekend and we celebrated with drinks. Chatted with a friend as well and told them the good news.

Today, the boss bought me lunch, some of the guys brang a cake, and everybody gave me hugs. Life was back on track!

Later today, the other female employee came and told me about how  the two male devs who suddenly had to deal with a tech problem during the event had actually gone and used a bot on the form, which is why the first set of votes were invalidated. She thought that I should know the truth.

On the one hand, I’m grateful that they cared so much (I’m one of just two women at a tech startup of 20 and have struggled to be accepted) but also concerned at how easily they congratulated me about winning and easily used it as proof that I “had what it takes” and “just had a run of bad luck.”

They casually lied to my face about how I was great and had won over everyone at the conference when I probably would have come in 5th had they not used the bot. My confidence is gone again. But had I lost, I also wouldn’t be feeling good about myself.

They also had no confidence in me that I could win it by myself. Was the bot a vote against me? Something to use to push me out later?

I also feel bad for the person who lost as he seemed so nice and genuine. I also feel like a fraud to my mother and best friend and really don’t want to have to tell them I lost (again).

Should I just keep quiet? Ask the guys about it? Talk to the boss/CEO? Should I still consider quitting? Could two software engineers even build a bot to fill in a form in 90 minutes?

Comment: Have you verified any of this at all beyond the word of the one co-worker? As the creator of the form was incompetent if a bot could so easily be made for it. 

And are you sure it was a bot and not your co-workers just voting several times using Incognito mode or something? The latter is extremely common at conferences with these awards.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser so the creator of the form is incompetent if a bot can be made for it, but just fine they rely on a cookie that can be bypassed by using incognito mode?

Comment: It seems to me like you don't know how to feel about this, and that's not something we can answer for you. Also consider the motivations of the person who told you the truth - maybe she wanted to take you down a peg.

Comment: "used a bot on the form, which is why the first set of votes were invalidated. "
if the first set of votes was invalidated, it looks like the situation was back to normal for the second, doesn't it ? did she tell you that they were still cheating during the second round ? it looks to me that you can assume you won in good faith.
anyway, without the ethical aspect, these people seems to care about you :)

Comment: @Based the cookie puts on extra hoop for bots at least (bot + wiping cookie requires some technical skill), but yes, the form really should have been a one time link sent to email or been done through a texting service which limited votes to one per phone number. 

I do not think either the unprotected form or the cookie form are well done. I just see both frequently.

Comment: @GlorfSf: it looks to me that they were better at cheating the second time.

Comment: I'd like to vote for *not* closing this.  This is clearly workplace-related, for someone suffering badly from Imposter Syndrome which is something that bites many of us. I think it would be profoundly disrespectful to the OP to try to silence her and negate her situation.

Comment: @Graham did someone vote to close this?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser yeah, there are several "off-topic"/"unclear" VTCs.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser There were four VTCs.  Currently it's on hold because it got a fifth.

Comment: @AndreiROM We can certainly give her suggestions for how to deal with having something rigged in your favour, looking at it without the emotional attachment.  All her reactions are entirely what I'd expect from anyone in that situation.  Contrary to the VTC reason, she explicitly ***has not*** asked for advice on a specific choice.  I think this is a near-perfect example of a question for the forum, and I have to ask what's the purpose of this forum if we can't ask bigger questions like this?  Surely the forum doesn't just exist to answer trivia like "should I polish my shoes?"

Comment: @graham - Workplace is not a forum, but a Q&A site. The questions here are meant to be widely applicable, and as such need to focus on specific issues. Check out this last paragraph: **Should I just keep quiet? Ask the guys about it? Talk to the boss/CEO? Should I still consider quitting? Could two software engineers even build a bot to fill in a form in 90 minutes?**. Had the OP asked: ***"How do I approach my boss about this situation?"***, or ***"How do I approach the two devs about this?"***, it would have been within scope. Help me decide who to speak to, and what to tell them, isn't.

Comment: I would keep quiet. They tried to help you, also, many people do the same in these contests, just using incognito mode instead of something like selenium. The thing that is really wrong here is that they have big mouths that they can't keep shut and your colleague spreads gossips. Also, you may need a psychologist to deal with your insecurities.

Comment: @Geronimo 'many people do the same' is no excuse.

Answer (score 40):

There are a few odd things that come to mind and a few questions. However my main concern is:

If two guys wrote the bot and deployed the victory, why did the other female colleague know about it? Must have been told and possibly told because you would then hear about it. There is a potential for it to spread and a future potential for it to be used against you if so chosen. What do the two guys have to gain with this act? If it were 100% to help, it would have\should have been kept 100% secret. My spidey sense is tingling over this one

The important thing here is that you did absolutely nothing wrong up to this point. Now you know. I do not know if there was a prize in the conference so there was remuneration or items involved, or if this was purely a recognition thing. Regardless, if you feel that you should not have won, you can simply ***renounce your victory***. Renounce on the basis that there are rumors circulating that there may have been some voting issues with the system doing the tallying. You do not need to reveal who mentioned it, you can simply defer and say that nothing is substantiated so you do not want to continue to propagate the rumor but you feel that just in case, the results should become invalid.

Perhaps a revote could happen. Perhaps the boss/CEO or whoever is in the position of authority will say that your presentation was good and deserved it anyways.

Then if things come out later on, you have already freed yourself of any guilt at all. You had your suspicion, you felt the needed to renounce, it was accepted, or not and it was nothing to do with you, so you are all good - on record.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to renounce the win. It would be an ethical win to the OP, if done.

Comment: -1 for suggesting to renounce the win and associate the company name with vote rigging

Comment: @LucasSeveryn But the company *was* associated with vote rigging... it's not the OP's duty to cover-up for something they disagree with.

Comment: It wasn't associated with it, the association will only be made once OP flags it.

Comment: It's a tough one, not the companies fault or the OPs fault. OP has to protect themselves foremost, the company may have to do the same at a later point in time for reputation purposes. In fact the company should do the same IMO, talk to conf organizers and withdraw based on information learned. It would look good on such a company to take the lead in moral accountability

Comment: I agree with you that something sounds fishy. How does the co-worker know?

Comment: @LucasSeveryn If the OP sticks to the rumors idea there is no reason to blame the company. It could have been some non-colleagues at the conference who liked the OP's talk and wanted to promote it.

Answer (score 16):

> Should I just keep quiet? Ask the guys about it? Talk to the boss/CEO?
>   Should I still consider quitting?

You should tell the conference organizers that you won the Bot's Choice Award through your coworkers cheating, so that they can award the rightful winner.

You should tell the cheating coworkers that you don't want to win that way.

Your decision to quit or not should have nothing to do with this silly incident one way or the other.

Comment: This is assuming that the OP's female colleague was correct in saying the coworkers set up the bot. What's to say she's not just jealous?

Comment: AND assuming the OP would not have won either way.

Comment: She won the Bot's Choice fair and square. It was the People's Choice in which the irregular activity is alleged to have occurred.

Comment: I would verify first, but this is spot on otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

> Was the bot a vote against me? Something to use to push me out later?

Why would it be? They're from your company. They're your friends.

> Could two software engineers even build a bot to fill in a form in 90 minutes?

Let me put it this way.

If there was little to no security on the form itself, it would take a non-programmer about 2 to 30 seconds to record such a script if an automated web testing tool like [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/introduction/the_selenium_project_and_tools/) was already installed on their browser.

> Should I still consider quitting?

Was prize money involved? I assume not.

Assuming you trust your CEO, you should consider telling him privately about this without naming the person who told you. He's the one who can advise you on this, but he's also the one who can make sure this doesn't happen again.

> And who knows? May be the higher management instructed those two developers to develop and run the bot. – Sara

One party who did know was the organizer(s) that ran the contest. The organizer(s) knew about the irregularities and they still chose to announce a winner anyway.

In any case, if it also turns out that the CEO was also aware, or that he doesn't want to reprimand the two guys that did this, then you may want to consider finding a new employer.

Comment: And who knows? May be the higher management instructed those two developers to develop and run the bot.

Comment: If it turns out that the CEO was in on it, or doesn't want to at least reprimand the people involved, then you should consider changing employer.

Comment: I was at an award ceremony today where they had a people's choice award and the form was protected by cookie only. People were constantly opening Incognito, voting, closing it, and starting over again. 

The vote was invalidated for having a multiple of the number of attendees. You don't need a bot (which as you said would be trivial to do), just diligent fingers.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser (1) This is a public event, not a company internal one (2) Knowing about a fraud and not reporting it can make you an accomplice (based on jurisdiction). (3) what others did, or did not, should not affect someone's decision in situations like this - best option is to stick with the fair game.

Comment: "Why would it be? They're from your company. They're your friends." This seems like an overly idealistic way of looking at things, especially since it wasn't too long ago when the big tech companies started a practice of regularly firing the lowest-performing individual on each team.

Comment: @nick012000, She is in a small startup, not a "big tech company".

Comment: @StephanBranczyk The point still remains, though. Just because they're your coworkers doesn't necessarily make them your friends, especially if they think that they might benefit from getting rid of you.

Comment: @nick012000, I get what you're saying, but that just doesn't sound feasible to me. There are other far more effective machinations you can use to get rid of someone.

Comment: 2 seconds. lol.

Comment: @dan-klasson, That was only a rough estimate, but yes, one second and a half to press the record button, press the submit button, and press the stop button (assuming the form doesn't require registration) and half a second to submit the request 50 times (although ideally, you'd want to throttle your 50 submissions to make them appear more organic). Selenium even offers a headless cloud-based solution, so if you have a paid account with them, you could have those 50 requests coming from different IP addresses if you so desired (instead of all those 50 submissions coming from your own browser).

Answer (score 1):

I would raise this with a manager.  This is called whistle blowing, and the correct course of action is to inform the company before notifying external bodies so that the company has a chance to defend itself and investigate.  It may turn out it wasn't rigged; and you were lied to...

Interacting with the external body directly would be very unwise and could have you fired on the spot.  You are protected from retribution when you whistleblow internally or law enforcement bodies.
You are not protected when you go to other 3rd parties.

Remember - you did not attend this conference personally - you attended it professionally; as such it is your company that will be impacted.  Don't break their trust.

Comment: I really don't understand why someone would downvote this.

Comment: This is the right answer